# How to update front-end when MongoDB model changes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Angular in the front-end and Node  for backend. I am using Mongoose with Node. MongoDB version is 3.4, so it cannot use Change Streams. Is there a way to inform Node directly when a new object is added in the DB collection? (without using timer-based DB calls, of course).